# Positive integers $a$ and $b$ are such that $a + b =\frac{ a}{b} +\frac{ b}{a}$. What is the value of $a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to take $a = 1$ and $b = 2$ and arrive at the conclusion that $a^2 + b^2 = 2$ which indeed is the answer.

However, I wanted to prove this equation algebraically without using the replacement technique.

Answer (score 3):

Either $a \ge b$ or $b \ge a$.  Without loss of generality (wolog) we might as well assume $b \ge a$, as were we to relabel variable $a$ with $b$ and $b$ with $a$ the expression would remain the same.  The proof will follow the same whichever $a$ or $b$ we assume to be the larger.  So let's assume $b \ge a$.

$a+b = \frac ab + \frac ba \le 1 + \frac ba \le 1 + b \le a + b $.

So $a+b = 1+b $ and $a = 1$.

So $1+ b = \frac 1b + b $ so $b = 1$.

So $a^2 +b^2 =2$.

Comment: I'm sorry but since I'm a beginner I'm unable to understand what you mean by "wolog".

Comment: Ooops.  Without loss of generality.  Either $b \ge a$ or $a \ge b$.  But if it's $a \ge b$ we can just relabel them so that $b \ge a$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a>1$ or $b>1$, then it follows that $a>\frac{a}{b}$ or $b>\frac{b}{a}$ so $$a+b=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}<a+b$$

Which is a contradiction.

Thus we conclude that $a,b \le 1$, and thus $a=b=1$. Therefore, the answer is $2$.